# If $\dfrac x{x^{1.5}}=(8x)^{-1}$ and $x>0$, then $x=\;?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> If $\dfrac x{x^{1.5}}=(8x)^{-1}$ and $x>0$, then $x=\;?$

I solved this many different ways and every time I get a different answer...

**Attempt #1:**

> $$\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac1{8x}$$ $$8x=\sqrt x$$ $$64x^2=x$$ $$x(64x-1)=0$$ $$x=0,\;\frac1{64}$$ $$x=\frac1{64}$$

**Attempt #2:**

> $$\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac1{8x}$$ 
> $$\frac{\sqrt x}x=\frac1{8x}$$ 
> $$x=8x\sqrt x$$ 
> $$\require{cancel}\cancel{8\sqrt x=0}\quad{8\sqrt x=1}$$
>  $$\cancel{x=0}\quad{\sqrt x=\frac18}$$ 
> $$\cancel{\text{no solution}}\quad x=\frac1{64}$$

**Attempt #3:**

> $$\require{cancel}\cancel{\frac x{x^{0.5}}=1}\quad \frac {8x}{x^{0.5}}=1$$ 
> $$\cancel{\sqrt x=1}\quad 8x=\sqrt x$$
>  $$\cancel{x=1}\quad x=\frac1{64}$$

Can someone provide a solution and also explain what I did wrong in each of these attempts? Thanks.

Comment: #2: `8 √x =0` Doesn't follow. #3: `x / x^0.5 = 1` Doesn't follow.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Every time I ask a question on this site now I get them...

Comment: Attempt 1 is correct. Attempt 2 has $\frac{x}{x} = 0$ rather than $1$. Attempt 3 is not even the same problem.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but my previous comment still stands as written. Since you edited the question anyway, one would have expected that you'd had doublechecked those steps by now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarifications

Comment: There are huge errors in 2nd and 3rd attempts, it will be good if you correct them.

Comment: I fixed everything

Comment: Well now that you've fixed it... do you have any question anymore?

Comment: @fleablood No, how can I show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is right but the problem says $x>0$

So, the solution will only be $\dfrac{1}{64}$

In second attempt your first three steps are correct but forth step should be-
$$0=8x\sqrt{x}-x$$
$$0=x(8\sqrt{x}-1)$$

In thirdt attempt, steps should be-
$$\dfrac{x}{x^{1.5}}=\dfrac{1}{8x}$$
$$\dfrac{8x}{x^{0.5}}=\dfrac{x}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{8x}{x^{0.5}}=1$$
$$8x=\sqrt{x}$$

I hope it'll help.

Comment: I put that the only solution was $\frac1{64}$...

Comment: So it was incorrect..??

Comment: Isn't that correct???

Comment: yeah! it's correct :)

Answer (score 1):

ʜᴇʟʟᴏ ᴅᴇᴀʀ!
$$\frac{x}{x^{1.5}} = (8x)^{-1}$$
$$x^{(1-1.5)} = \frac{1}{8x}$$
$$ x^{-0.5}= \frac{1}{8x}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{8x}$$
$$x = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{8}$$
On squaring both sides,
$$x^2=\frac{x}{64}$$
Given $x>0$:
$$x = \frac{1}{64}$$

Comment: Shuchi , Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax while formatting your answers/questions. Read it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also the answer was incorrect, so I fixed it for you.